# using arrays to solve an equation

Tags: c++, arrays

so i wrote this code in c++ to solve this equation (x+y+z=30) where each of these variables has a limited amount of possible of values (1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15) so repetition is allowed and here's my code :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

int x[8]={1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15};
int y[8]={1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15};
int z[8]={1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15};
    for (int i=0; i<8; i++)
    {

        for (int j=0; j<8; j++)
        {

            for (int k=0; k<8; j++)

            {

                if (x[i]+y[j]+z[k]==30)
                {
                   cout << x[i] << "\n" << y[j] << "\n" << z[k]<< "\n"<< endl;
                   break;
                }


            }
        }
    }

}
```

now i don't know if this is the right way to approach it (I'm a beginner) but still this program did okay since it gave set of three number that did equal to 30 but it didn't stick to the possible values e.g (7,22,1), now that what you see their is the best i could come up with other attempts or fixes just made things worse e.g crashing or what so ever.
if you could help that would be great and most importantly tell me where i went wrong as this whole purpose of this is to learn not solve the problem.
thank you so much in advance !

Comment: Use a debugger.  If you don't know how to use a debugger, this is a good time to learn.  With a debugger, you can execute each statement and *watch* the values in the variables.  Also, much more efficient than posting to StackOverflow and *waiting* for an answer.

Comment: `for (int k=0; k<8; j++)` Did you mean `k++`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using *break* statement which only breaks one of the loops. You have nested loops in your program, so i would recommend you to use *goto:* instead.

```
for (int i=0; i<8; i++)
  {
   for (int j=0; j<8; j++)
    {
        for (int k=0; k<8; j++)<----- it should  be k++ 
        {
            if (x[i]+y[j]+z[k]==30)
            {

               goto stop;
            }
        }
     }
   }

  stop:  
  cout << x[i] << "\n" << y[j] << "\n" << z[k]<< "\n"<< endl;
```

I actually ran the code and there is 2 more problems:

1. As mentioned on the answer below, it 3 odd numbers never add up to 30;
2. variables i , j and k need to be global variables. So initialize them before using in loops. Then it should work perfectly(if the number isn't even).

Comment: Or move it into a function, if you'd feel dirty using a `goto`, despite this being the only use case making sense.

Comment: I have no problem with goto but there are people that hate it.  If you didn't want to use goto you could just store all the results and run the loops to the end and then print out all the results.  That way break and goto aren't needed at all.

Comment: @hauron I agree with you.  in that case, return is just goto with more boilerplate and doesn't make the code more readable because then the logic is all spread out.  A C++ lambda allows the function to use return instead of goto and still be local to the algorithm but I still don't think I would prefer that...

Comment: thanx, and yes im aware of that mistake regarding the k, also using goto is indeed a good idea but rather an easy one like i said im only here to learn but i will definitely give it a try .....but still i did do some tweaking in the code for example i made my final value 28 instead of 30 to avoid this mathematical issue (although 30 was the goal) yet somehow it still gave me results that are not declared in the array such as 22 and i dont know why ...... thanx

Comment: @fahad97azawi As i said before 3 odd numbers can never add up to a even number as 28 or 30. Try 27 and it should work finely.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see 22 in the values you initialized the arrays with. You also can just use one array with the possible values; 3 arrays are not needed.

I see that you only have odd integers as possible values. 3 odd integers can never sum up to an even integer like 30, so there is no solution to your problem as stated. The one solution you provided has 22 as one value, an even integer.

Comment: yes, i understand that logic actually this equation came as riddle to me and i was never able to solve it so i thought i use my programming skill, and yes 22  is not in the variables it seems that my program is just finding any three combination to get the result of 30 instead of what it should (which is either returning a solution from given possibilities OR at least crash as like you suggested it's impossible) also you had my interest on  how to make them all in one array as there's three diffrent variables that i need so it would be great if you could explain

Comment: You seem to have already accepted an answer that doesn't actually answer your question.

Comment: (A) May be you could post the output from your program? (B) I did not suggest a program would (or should) crash; it would/should just exit without finding any solution. (C) You could create one array called possibleValues[] with the same values as x[] and use it everywhere either x[], y[], or z[] is used. Then you could get rid of x[], y[], and z[].